# Adding/removing a class on a ReactJS component when a user scrolls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change a class on my navigation bar, so when a user scrolls it fades from transparent to opaque. From following some other questions on here and other solutions online i've come up with the below and tweaked it a few ways, but nothing seems to be working.

I added in a console log to error check but it never runs.

Page component

```
import React from 'react'
import Nav from './_includes/Nav.jsx'
import VideoBanner from './_includes/VideoBanner.jsx'
import Section from './_includes/Section.jsx'
import { object } from 'prop-types'

class Homepage extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    if (props.initialSetup) props.initialSetup()
    this.state = {
      navOpaque: true
    }
    this.handleScroll=this.handleScroll.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll () {
    const { navOpaque } = this.state
    const { pageYOffset } = window;

    if (pageYOffset >= 10 ) {
      this.setState ({
        navOpaque: false
      })
    }

    console.log('you have scrolled')

    return navOpaque
  }

  render () {
    const { navOpaque } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="homepageContainer">
        <Nav
          navOpaque={navOpaque}
        />
        <VideoBanner />
        <Section />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Homepage.propTypes = {
  dataSource: object,
  domainSettings: object,
  pageData: object.isRequired,
}

export default Homepage
```

Nav component

```
import React from 'react'
import NavItem from './NavItem.jsx'
import { bool } from 'prop-types'
import classnames from 'classnames'

class Nav extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeTab: '',
      highlight: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick (activeTab) {
    if (!activeTab) activeTab = ''
    this.setState({
      activeTab
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { highlight } = this.state
    const { navOpaque } = this.props

    const navClass = classnames({
      'opaque': navOpaque,
      'navbar': true,
      'navbar-default': true,
      'navbar-fixed-top': true,
      'hidden-print': true,
      'navbar-megamenu': true
    })

    return (
        <nav id='header' className={navClass} role='navigation'>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='navbar-header'>
                <button type='button' className='navbar-toggle hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg'>
                  <span className='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span className='icon-bar' />
                  <span className='icon-bar' />
                  <span className='icon-bar' />
                </button>
              <a className='navbar-brand' href='/'>Brand</a>
            </div>
            <div className='col-md-4 collapse navbar-collapse'>
              <ul className='nav navbar-nav list-inline'>
                {Object.keys(navConfig).map(function (listGroup, key) {
                  return(
                    <NavItem
                      key={key}
                      listGroup={listGroup}
                      linkData={navConfig[listGroup]}
                      highlight={ navConfig[listGroup].text === 'test' ? {highlight} : null }
                    />
                  )
                })}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    )
  }

}

Nav.propTypes = {
  navOpaque: bool
}

export default Nav
```

Comment: Check if `Nav` component is re-rendered when `Homepage` changes its state.

Comment: how would i do this?

Comment: add `console.log` inside render method of `Nav` and check if it prints when you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class' attribute `ref` with `React.CreateRef()` and attach it to the element where you want to remove classes on scroll.

Then in your `handleScroll` method, take `this.ref.current` 
and do whatever you want on the `classList`

`this.ref.current.classList.remove('my-class')`

Hope this help.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be right, at least to have the console.log to be executed when you scroll.

You might try to check if your class container has a height that allows you to scroll.

Check if this example helps:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nwr99l5l8p

Note that in the styles.css, the container has a height of 200vh, allowing the scrolling.

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200vh;
 }
```

Comment: I changed the height but it didn't seem to affect it, interestingly i also added a console.log to componentDidMount like you did in your example and that also doesn't run.

Comment: So this provides you with a clue that something else is wrong, and probably nothing to do with the addEventListener and the handleScroll execution.